# Renaming multiple files in python

Tags: python

I wanted to know what is the easiest way to rename multiple files using re module in python if at all it is possible.

In my directory their are 25 files all with the file names in the format ' A unique name followed by 20 same  characters.mkv '

What I wanted was to delete all the 20 characters.

How can I do this using Python if at all it is possible :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the new name:

```
>>> re.sub(r'.{20}(.mkv)', r'\1', 'unique12345678901234567890.mkv')
'unique.mkv'
```

Or without regex:

```
>>> 'unique12345678901234567890.mkv'[:-24] + '.mkv'
'unique.mkv'
```

To rename the file use `os.rename(old, new)`: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename

To get a list of the files to rename use `glob.glob('*.mkv')`: http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob

Putting that all together we get:

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.mkv'):
    if len(filename) > 24:
        os.rename(filename, filename[:-24] + '.mkv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are cutting out a specific number of characters from an easily identified point in the string, the `re` module is somewhat overkill. You can prepare the new filename as:

```
new_name = old_name.rsplit('.', 1)[0][:-20] + '.mkv'
```

To find the files, look up `os.listdir` (or, if you want to look into directories recursively, `os.walk`), and to rename them, see `os.rename`.

The `re` module would be useful if there are other .mkv's in the directory that you don't want to rename, so that you need to do more careful checking to identify the "target" filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob` to find the filenames, slice the strings, and use `os.rename()` to rename them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
>>> import os
>>> doIt = False
>>> for filename in ( x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith('.mvk')):
...     newname = filename[:-24] + filename[-4:]
...     if doIt:
...         os.rename(filename,newname)
...         print "Renaming {0} to {1}".format(filename,newname)
...     else:
...         print "Would rename {0} to {1}".format(filename,newname)
...
```

When manipulating files, always have a dryrun. Change `doIt` to `True`, to actually move the files.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) and [os.rename](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename). The rest if for you to figure it out!

And yes, this is entirely possible and easy to do in Python.